# Many-to-Many Relationship in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, relationships, ef-core-2.1

I am trying to learn relationships with Ef Core 2.1 . I want to make a small social media sample. Here is user entity :

```
 public class IUser {
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
 }
```

And some user types that was inherited from the IUser :

```
 public class Employee : IUser {
 }


 public class Manager : IUser {
}


public class Trainee : IUser{
}
```

Then, I try to make friendlist. There are lots of many to many relationship between them like : 
Trainee and Employee, 
Trainee and Manager,
Manager and Employee. 
Employee and Trainee
Trainee and Trainee etc.

And I created the relationships like this :

```
public class FriendList {
    [Key]
    public Guid FriendListId { get; set; }

    public Guid RequestedById { get; set; }
    public Guid RequestedToId { get; set; }
    public Trainee RequestedBy { get; set; }
    public Trainee RequestedTo { get; set; }
 }
```

There are 9 entity in this way. Is there any way to create this relationships briefly.

Comment: `FriendList` is not a list at all. All it contains are the details about a singular friendship. Can you choose a better name for your class, or explain how it is a list? Also, why model the same relationship between different implementations of `IUser`? Can you make the relationship generic (i.e., replace `public Trainee RequestedBy` with  `public IUser RequestedBy`)? And finally, you usually don't model many to many relationships in code like this. You choose a perspective (one side of the relationship) and then build your model from that perspective. For example, one user has many friends.

Comment: Yep. Instead of the (useless) interface, use base entity and [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance).

Comment: Or composition. F.e. roles, like, can't a manager also be an employee? Or an employee *become* a manager? Whichever it's gonna be, it'll leave you with only two entities, User and Friendship (or a more formal name like Partnership).